# Replace part of string in string.format

Tags: c#, .net

I have XML string and want to replace value of one of my attributes. Is is possible to replace value using string.format?

Eg: XML String is something like below:

```
<ParentNode>
   <ChildNode>Special `~@#$%^&amp;*()_+-=[]|:;\'/.,<>?  message0</ChildNode>
</ParentNode>
```

Now I want to replace `<>` with `&lt;&gt;`
How can I manipulate string to replace these characters?

Comment: Can you fix the source of the XML to produce valid XML in the first place?

Comment: so you have this in a string? or is it an xml file? I'm confused

Comment: No. string.Format() is to format something for display. string.Replace() is what you want.

Comment: Fixing XML with a regex is asking for trouble. Use an XML parser. Also, you don't have any XML attributes.

Comment: @MicrosoftDN I want to encode these characters so that DOMParser can create XmlDoc.

Comment: Actually sounds like you should be html encoding (you already have `&amp;`, so this is partly done...).

Comment: @greenfeet It is in string format

Comment: Where did the string come from in the first place? You should first see if you can't tackle this at the source rather than trying to clumsily fix it on your end.

Comment: @ChiragFanse Use an xml parser like XDocument or XmlDocument. You don't need to encode it. Parsers can handle it for you.

Comment: If it is *always the case* that you have `<>` in the contents of a node, and *not anywhere else*, then a simple `myString.Replace("<>","&lt;&gt;")` would fix it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this pure string methods approach:

```
string input = @"<ParentNode>
<ChildNode>Special `~@#$%^&amp;*()_+-=[]|:;\'/.,<>?  message0</ChildNode>
</ParentNode>";
int indexOfChildNode = input.IndexOf("<ChildNode>", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
if (indexOfChildNode >= 0)
{
    int endIndexOfChildNode = input.IndexOf("</ChildNode>", indexOfChildNode + "<ChildNode>".Length, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    if (endIndexOfChildNode >= 0)
    {
        string before = input.Substring(0, indexOfChildNode);
        string after = input.Substring(endIndexOfChildNode + "</ChildNode>".Length);
        int indexToken = indexOfChildNode + "<ChildNode>".Length;
        int length = endIndexOfChildNode - indexToken;
        string token = input.Substring(indexToken, length);
        input = string.Format("{0}<ChildNode>{1}</ChildNode>{2}"
            , before
            , token.Replace(">", "&gt;").Replace("<", "&lt;")
            , after);
    }
}
```

However, if you only want to replace `<>` it's much simpler:

```
input = input.Replace("<>","&lt;&gt;")
```